# How to graph in Processing from an arduino

Tags: processing

I'm trying to do something pretty simple which is just to output the values from a photocell attached to an arduino to a Processing graph. I have managed to output the values to the Processing console as floats and a sketch window pops up but there is no graph- I'm sure it's something straightforward but I don't know what.I've got a feeling its to do with the scale of what I'm plotting (the println gives me values between 0.2 and 1.1) but I think I'm lost in the scaling of the graph hence no output. Here is my Processing code:

```java
import processing.serial.*;

Serial myPort;        // The serial port
int xPos = 1;         // horizontal position of the graph 

//Variables to draw a continuous line.
int lastxPos=1;
int lastheight=0;

void setup () {
  // set the window size:
  size(600, 400);        

  // List all the available serial ports
  // Check the listed serial ports in your machine
  // and use the correct index number in Serial.list()[].

  myPort = new Serial(this, "/dev/tty.usbmodem1421", 9600);  //

  // A serialEvent() is generated when a newline character is received :
  myPort.bufferUntil('\n');
  background(0);      // set inital background:
}
void draw () {
  // everything happens in the serialEvent()
}

void serialEvent (Serial myPort) {
  // get the ASCII string:
  String inString = myPort.readStringUntil('\n');
  inString = trim(inString);  // trim off whitespaces.
  //println(inString);
  if (inString != null) {

    float inByte = float(inString);           // convert to a number.
    inByte = map(inByte, 0, 1023, 0, height); //map to the screen height.
println(inByte);
    //Drawing a line from Last inByte to the new one.
    stroke(127,34,255);     //stroke color
    strokeWeight(4);        //stroke wider
    line(lastxPos, lastheight, xPos, height - inByte); 
    lastxPos= xPos;
    lastheight= int(height-inByte);

    // at the edge of the window, go back to the beginning:
    if (xPos >= width) {
      xPos = 0;
      lastxPos= 0;
      background(0);  //Clear the screen.
    } 
    else {
      // increment the horizontal position:
      xPos++;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While I don't have the arduino input, by removing those parts I was able to draw a purple line. However, it was simply drawing at the bottom of the window, as I used a static `"0.5"` string value for inString, to stay in the same order of magnitude as your input values. Simply multiplying the value when converting to float, i.e.:

`float inByte = float(inString)*500;` ,

drew the line further up. You could try multiplying the float input by `height`, or maybe even `1023`, and it should stay well within limits. Multiplying by `height` on the 0.5 value I used, still draws the line closer to the bottom than the middle (i.e. `height/2`).

Below is the complete code I used to draw a purple line across the canvas. As you can see, I simply moved everything into `draw()`, and removed the serial input parts:

```java
int xPos = 1;         // horizontal position of the graph 

//Variables to draw a continuous line.
int lastxPos=1;
int lastheight=0;

void setup () {
  // set the window size:
  size(600, 400);        

  // List all the available serial ports
  // Check the listed serial ports in your machine
  // and use the correct index number in Serial.list()[].
  background(0);      // set inital background:
}
void draw () {
  // get the ASCII string:
  String inString = "0.5";
  inString = trim(inString);  // trim off whitespaces.
  //println(inString);
  if (inString != null) {
    float inByte = float(inString)*1023;           // convert to a number.
    inByte = map(inByte, 0, 1023, 0, height); //map to the screen height.
    println(inByte);
    //Drawing a line from Last inByte to the new one.
    stroke(127,34,255);     //stroke color
    strokeWeight(4);        //stroke wider
    line(lastxPos, lastheight, xPos, height - inByte); 
    lastxPos= xPos;
    lastheight= int(height-inByte);

    // at the edge of the window, go back to the beginning:
    if (xPos >= width) {
      xPos = 0;
      lastxPos= 0;
      background(0);  //Clear the screen.
    } 
    else {
      // increment the horizontal position:
      xPos++;
    }
  }
}
```